# Optimizing ngFor in Angular2 with dropdowns in child components

Tags: angular

I'm trying to address some performance issues in my Angular2 app during a large ngFor operation.  It is generating about 50 identical bootstrap dropdown menus for 50 different dropdown buttons and the performance is unacceptable.

If I wasn't using Angular2, I would probably just create a single menu and then use jQuery to move it around to where the user was clicking.  But that wouldn't be the angular2 way to do it.

```
<div *ngFor="let configField of selectedMappingConfiguration.ConfigurationFields | visibleFieldsOnly">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">      
        </button>
          <!-- This is what I need to optimize  -->
        <div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu dropdown-menu-right" *ngIf="mappingDropdownValues">
            <div class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let val of mappingDropdownValues" (click)="mappingChanged(configField, val)">
                {{val.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What are different approaches I could take to handle this performance problem?  If I wanted to get deep into the DOM, how would I do that in an Angular way?

Comment: What do you mean by "performance is unacceptable"? What are the concret signs?

Comment: It's being rendered anew when a user selects a different configuration, and the render operation takes about 3 seconds.  If I take out the child dropdown, it takes about 500ms

Comment: we had basically the same thing in angular1 and it was must faster than angular2